# iOS Getting at an SSL public key / modulus Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, nsurlconnection

I need to verify that a SSL certificate is not only from my domain and from a trusted Certificate Authority, but also it has a specific public key.

```
SecCertificateRef serverCertificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0);
SecKeyRef key = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust);

DLog(@"Cert: %@ Key: %@",serverCertificate,key);
```

The cert here is fine, the key logs out the public key, but I cannot open up the `SecKeyRef` to grab the public key and do a string comparison. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: are you solved this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C / C pulling private key (modulus) from SecKeyRef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962463/objective-c-c-pulling-private-key-modulus-from-seckeyref)