# Get public/private key from certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, public-key-encryption

I try to get public or private key from certificate saved on device.
I'm using this method:

```
    - (SecKeyRef)publicKeyFromFile:(NSString *)path
{
    NSData * certificateData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path]];

    if (certificateData != nil && certificateData.bytes != 0) {

        CFDataRef cfDataPath = CFDataCreate(NULL, [certificateData bytes], [certificateData length]);
        SecCertificateRef certificateFromFile = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, cfDataPath);

        if (certificateFromFile) {
            SecPolicyRef secPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
            SecTrustRef trust;
            SecTrustCreateWithCertificates( certificateFromFile, secPolicy, &trust);
            SecTrustResultType resultType;
            SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &resultType);
            SecKeyRef publicKeyObj = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust);

            return publicKeyObj;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

There is data in cfDataPath, but certificateFromFile is always nil...

Does anyone know where's the problem?

Comment: Your tag already indicates this question is about iOS. No need to add that to the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doc refers:

> Obtaining a SecKeyRef Object for Public Key Cryptography
>   Extracting Keys from the Keychain If you are using existing public and private keys from your keychain, read Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Programming Guide to learn how to retrieve a SecKeychainItemRef object for that key.
>   Once you have obtained a SecKeychainItemRef, you can cast it to a SecKeyRef for use with this API.
>   Importing Existing Public and Private Keys Importing and exporting public and private key pairs is somewhat more complicated than generating new keys because of the number of different key formats in common use.
>   This example describes how to import and export a key pair in PEM (Privacy Enhanced Mail) format.

Read more : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/SigningandVerifying/SigningandVerifying.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358

Try with this:

```
  -(BOOL)trustCertFromChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
 {
SecTrustResultType trustResult;
SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);

//DLog(@"Failed: %@",error.localizedDescription);
//DLog(@"Status: %li | Trust: %@ - %li",(long)status,trust,(long)trustResult);

if (status == 0 && (trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified || trustResult == kSecTrustResultProceed)) {

    SecKeyRef serverKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust);

    NSString *certPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MYCert" ofType:@"der"];
    NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:certPath];
    SecCertificateRef localCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)certData);

    SecKeyRef localKey = NULL;
    SecTrustRef localTrust = NULL;
    SecCertificateRef certRefs[1] = {localCertificate};
    CFArrayRef certArray = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (void *)certRefs, 1, NULL);
    SecPolicyRef policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
    OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(certArray, policy, &localTrust);

    if (status == errSecSuccess)
        localKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(localTrust);

    CFRelease(localTrust);
    CFRelease(policy);
    CFRelease(certArray);

     if (serverKey != NULL && localKey != NULL && [(__bridge id)serverKey isEqual:(__bridge id)localKey])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}

//DLog(@"Failed: %@",error.localizedDescription);

return NO;
  }
```

Follow the accepted answer for more details: [Objective-C / C pulling private key (modulus) from SecKeyRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962463/objective-c-c-pulling-private-key-modulus-from-seckeyref)